# asp.net mvc application down

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api

I have a Live website called API Web, build with ASP.NET MVC 4.
This application is to provide a JavaScript files for other websites.
I have 20 websites requesting a JavaScript to it.

But, sometimes this API Web is going down and I have a trouble to make the application live again.
I don't know why this happen, and how can I solve this issue?

**EDIT**

This is the controller, if the website requesting a path say http://api.example.com/get/js/folderA?js=jquery.js
the application will return a javascript content.
but, the requesting website will load slower. and I think if the API Web had too much request, it will going down (bottleneck issue).

```
public ActionResult js(string id, string js) {
            string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/content/" + id + "/js/" + CryptKeys.Decrypt(js) + "");

            string contentType = "text/javascript";
            var file = System.IO.File.Open(fileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            var stream = (Stream)(file);

            return new FileStreamResult(stream, contentType);

        }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, my psychic debugger is down.  How do you expect anyone to help you, given the information you have given?

Comment: I'm not sure how to track this error, I checked the log on IIS and it's working properly. Is it possible to many request on application will causing a down?

Comment: Anything is possible, since you have given nothing to go on.  It could be martians for all we know.  It might help if you told us more than "It doesn't work".

Comment: please check my update, I put my logic there. sorry, noob in action. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that you are not closing the filestream opened by `System.IO.File.Open` class which may be leading to next call to return the same file in throwing an exception. And because the exception is not handled, this may eventually be leading to site being shutting down.

Did you check for error logs in event viewer?

Based on your inputs below, could you try this piece of code? Notice the `using` block that I have added

```
public ActionResult js(string id, string js) {
        string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/content/" + id + "/js/" + CryptKeys.Decrypt(js) + "");

        string contentType = "text/javascript";
        using(var file = System.IO.File.Open(fileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            var stream = (Stream)(file);

            return new FileStreamResult(stream, contentType);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you post the whole error along with all the messages instead of just the error code?

Comment: A quick search on error code 3005 tells me that apppool has crashed. That strengthens my doubt that the filestream that you are not closing is causing the apppool to crash when same file is being tried to open twice.

Comment: I see, should I use Asynch methods to handle this issue? remembering there are many request from client to access the file.

Comment: You just need to dispose the filestream, I have updated my answer to include a code sample. You can give that a try.

Comment: I have tried that one, but the page show error "Cannot access a closed file."

Comment: There are possibly two requests trying to access the same file concurrently